# Python-docx: How do I place a pandas table at a specific position in the word document

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I have a template I populate with a table or pandas dataframe. The template has pre-existing tables already. What I would like to do is to insert the pandas table between two pre-existing tables without overlap.

I do know how to insert a table using for instance:

```
            from docx import Document
            import pandas as pd

            pandas_table = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Paul'],'Age':[25,40]})


            doc = docx.Document()            

            h = doc.add_table(pandas_table.shape[0]+1, pandas_table.shape[1]) 

            h.style = 'Table Grid'      
     
            for j in range(pandas_table.shape[-1]):
                h.cell(0,j).text = pandas_table.columns[j]

            # add the rest of the data frame
            for i in range(pandas_table.shape[0]):
                for j in range(pandas_table.shape[-1]):
                    h.cell(i+1,j).text = str(pandas_table.values[i,j])

            for row in h.rows:
                for cell in row.cells:
                    paragraphs = cell.paragraphs
                    for paragraph in paragraphs:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            font = run.font
                            font.name = 'Calibri'
                            font.size= Pt(10.2)

            doc.save('path/to/filename.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go the easy way:

1. I placed my table in the template where I wanted it to be positioned and,
2. Loaded the template:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document('path/to/template.docx')
```

3. Then fetched the tables in the template where the one I was interested in was second in the list. Updated it and saved the document. As simple as that.

```
tables = doc.tables
tables[1].cell(1,0) = '$'+str(1000)
tables[1].cell(1,1) = str(2.5)+'%'

doc.save('path/to/template.docx')
```